# Как получить Handle окна?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используется же WinAPI функции?

У меня есть список заголовков процессов:

```
string[] names = new string[] {"TeamViewer", "Bandicam", "и.т.д"};
```

К примеру изменили процесс, как мне найти эти процессы через Handle окна?

Пройтись по всем процессам, а дальше что используется?

```
foreach (var processes in Process.GetProcesses())
{
   // как тут найти изменённый процесс?
}
```

Comment: ты уж решись, тебе нужен Title, Handle или processName. То на что указывает стрелочка -- это Title окна. Но подписано как хендл почему-то.

Comment: "А дальше что используется?" -- для чего используется?

Comment: @Andrew, Handle нужно получить.

Comment: @AK, нужно сравнить все имена процессов со списом из names и убить. Но как убить если процесс изменён. Поэтому хочу попробовать найти точное имя как на скриншоте.

Comment: Автор вопроса явно не может высказать нормально словами что конкретно он хочет получить. Вопрос постоянно меняется. Голосую за закрытие по причине "непонятна суть вопроса"

Answer (score 1):

```
IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
{
  if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains(wName))
  {
      hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
  }
}
return hWnd; //Should contain the handle but may be zero if the title doesn't match
```

кейворды для гугления: get window handle by title

---

> Как использовать этот пример для убийства процессов?

```
foreach (Process pr in Process.GetProcesses())
{
  if (pr.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Team Viewer"))
  {
      pr.CloseMainWindow();
  }
}
```

Кейворды для гугления: kill process by title c#

Comment: А если MainWindowTitle не совпадает со списком wName ? ну допустим если процесс изменён то получается и в MainWindowTitle будет отображаться тоже самое?!

Comment: что значит процесс изменен? Кем изменен? Почему должен менятся WindowTitle?

Comment: Не работает если имя процесса изменено :(

Comment: у тебя в голове полная каша. Ты путаешь имя процесса, хендл и тайтл. Я не могу читать твои мысли и я не знаю что ты имеешь ввиду. Имя процесса никак не влияет на тот код который я написал. ПРЯМ ВООБЩЕ. И я не знаю что такое "процесс изменен" и как это случается и вообще что ты имеешь ввиду.